# Scanner while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

So I am having issues with a while loop(been awhile). I am getting a compiling error while trying to set a scanner object to do a program while user input is "y". How do I get this to work? Error is at where choice = Scanner.nextLine

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Computes the area and perimeter of selected figures.
 */
public class ComputeAreaAndPerimeter {

    /**
     * The main program performs the following steps.
     * 1. It asks the user for the type of figure.
     * 2. It asks the user for the characteristics of that figure.
     * 3. It computes the perimeter.
     * 4. It computes the area.
     * 5. It displays the result.
     * @param args The command line arguments -- not used
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Shape myShape;
        double perimeter;
        double area;
        myShape = getShape(); // Ask for figure type
        myShape.readShapeData(); // Read the shape data
        perimeter = myShape.computePerimeter(); // Compute perimeter
        area = myShape.computeArea(); // Compute the area
        displayResult(area, perimeter); // Display the result
        System.exit(0); // Exit the program
        String choice;
    }

    /**
     * Ask the user for the type of figure.
     * @return An instance of the selected shape
     */

        public static Shape getShape() {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Do you want to run the program? Y or N");
            choice = Scanner.nextLine(); //Error is here
            while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
            {
                System.out.println("Enter C for circle");
                System.out.println("Enter R for Rectangle");
                System.out.println("Enter T for Right Triangle");
                String figType = in.next();
                if (figType.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
                    return new Circle();
                } else if (figType.equalsIgnoreCase("r")) {
                    return new Rectangle();
                } else if (figType.equalsIgnoreCase("t")) {
                    return new RtTriangle();
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
                System.out.println("Run prgram again?");
            }
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
    }

    /**
     * Display the result of the computation.
     * @param area The area of the figure
     * @param perim The perimeter of the figures
     */
    private static void displayResult(double area, double perim) {
        System.out.printf("The area is %.2f%nThe perimeter is %.2f%n",
                area, perim);
    }
}
/*</listing>*/
```

Comment: Scanner.nextLine() returns a String, see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 3):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Do you want to run the program? Y or N");
choice = Scanner.nextLine(); //Error is here
while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
```

The issue is you are improperly using `Scanner`.

It should be something like:

```
String userChoice = choice.nextLine();
```

To use it in your loop more effectively, you can try something like:

```
String userChoice = choice.nextLine();
while (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
    // do your loop logic
    // then, to be structured, at the end of your loop, do...
    System.out.print("Do you want to run the program again? Y or N: ");
    userChoice = choice.nextLine();
}
```

This will re-test the condition after each loop has run. If the user selects "n", the loop will exit naturally.

Answer (score 1):

You should only declare one `Scanner` to read from the input stream

`Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`

And then whenever you want to prompt for input, you can call `scanner.next()` and it will wait on input.

`String input = scanner.next();`

An example of this being done could be:

```
public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {

    String input = scanner.next();
    System.out.println(input);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Do you want to run the program? Y or N");
String choice = in.nextLine(); 
while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
{
    //rest of code
```

You had created an extra `Scanner` which you don't need. You also were getting the `nextLine()` incorrectly.